# Movie where nun raises a girl from an egg who is then kidnapped

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was very young, I saw a movie where an egg is left on a nun's doorstep and a baby hatches from it. The nun raises it and the girl grows up. When she grows up, two freaky-looking guys grab her and say, "We're taking you back to where you belong."

That's all I can recall, but if anyone had any ideas on what the movie might be, please let me know. This is the best I could string together of the few things I saw. It's been getting at me for years!

Comment: This movie never existed. Forget it - it never happened. It was a terrible dream.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._(film)

Comment: I hear there are nightmares about Matrix sequels too @CBredlow

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be referring to this iconic scene from the smash hit film [**Super Mario Bros**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtMZKYnLg5c).

[image]

> **Daisy:** *Where are you taking me?*
>
> **Henchman:** *Back to where you belong.*

As you can see, the nuns find an egg laid by the mother of Princess Daisy. Later, the Princess is kidnapped by the evil King Koopa, superbly portrayed by [Dennis Hopper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHYRoeHZau8) in what some consider his finest role.

Comment: Got this straight away from the title. **DAMN.** Almost answered one!